# Django - несколько вопросов

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, git

Делаю сайт на Django на текущий момент в связке с SQLite, но по мере роста базы данных появились проблемы в скорости работы. На текущий момент разработка и наполнение идет на двух компьютерах одним человеком, синхронизация с рабочим сервером через Github (понимаю извращение).

Типичный пример: лечу в самолете, пока лечу наполняю базу, приземлился - сделал git push, затем на сервере git stash && git pull, но это явно не фень-шуй...

Как красиво перейти на PostgreSQL, причем в идеале хотелось бы так, чтобы наполнение сайта могло быть и через сайт и с компьютера разработчика и все потом синхронизировалось?

Comment: Задавайте вопросы по отдельности.

Comment: несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Answer (score 0):

1. перейти легко, просто сменить драйвер базы и указать, хост, порт, имя базы, логопас и выполнить миграции.
   Не очень понял, что значит с пк разработчика? Базу можно набивать откуда угодно, через сторонний клиент типо DBeaver или любой код/клиент который только вздумается. Данные можно перенести тем же DBeaver или погуглить чтото вроде migrate data from sqlite to postgresql
2. Снова не очень понял, наполнение в смысле вы наполняете базу из кода вашего приложения? Хардкодите?
3. Я использую в качестве планировщика задач celery, он имеет интеграцию с django и задачами можно рулить как через админку, так и через свою форму/апи/ещё чтото. Если ничего не выдумывать, можно создавать и удалять задачи просто в админке джанго. А задача это просто функция в вашем приложении с декоратором shared_task например, в которой всё что напишите будет.
   [First steps with Django](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html)